# where is the default cursor location of the edittext in Oreo?

Tags: android, android-edittext, cursor

Prior to Android 8.0, the default cursor location of edittext is 0: the cursor is before the text.

But in android 8.0, the cursor is after the text.

How to resolve that ?

I tried to use edittext.setSelection, but it does not work.

Comment: setSelection(0),but it still no work

Comment: where are you using this method?

Comment: I used edittext.setSelection in the  create method when the activity is created. But it didn't work. Then i try to use setSelection in the Resume method. but still didn't work